# How do we reorder bars of Barchart created using dplyr

Tags: r

I have created a barchart in R studio using dplyr. The bars are not in the right order. Kindly help me reorder 0,1-5,6-10,11-15 and Above 15
I have used the following code to create the chart

```r
BarChart(Number.of.Beetle, 
         data = g, 
         by1 = Locality.Division, 
         main = "Beetle number vs Locality Division" , 
         xlab = "Number of beetle" , 
         ylab = "Locality Division")
```

[image]

Comment: If you provide a reproducible part of your dataset, it would be easier to solve your issue.(in dput format prefered).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the BarChart() function, and it's not part of base R. Can you also include what package contains this function? If it's well behaved, BarChart() should pay attention to the order of the Locality.Division factor. See this SO answer for how to order a factor for plotting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

##----------------------------------------
## Creating a dataset to simulate yours
##----------------------------------------

df <- tibble(
  beetle = sample(0:25, 500, replace = TRUE),
  loclity_division = sample(c("Municipality", "Village"), 500, replace = T),
)

df$beetle <-  ifelse(df$beetle > 1 & df$beetle <= 5, "1-5",
              ifelse(df$beetle > 5 & df$beetle <= 10, "6-10",
              ifelse(df$beetle > 10 & df$beetle <= 15, "11-15",
              ifelse(df$beetle > 15, "Above 15", "0"
              ))))


##--------------------------------------
## Determine the custom order of levels
##--------------------------------------

df$beetle <- factor(df$beetle, levels = c("0", "1-5", "6-10", "11-15", "Above 15"))


##----------------------
## Plotting by ggplot
##----------------------

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = beetle, fill = beetle)) +
    geom_bar(width = 0.6) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(vars(loclity_division))
```

[image]